# Python Import Error: Undefined Symbol for Custom C Module

Tags: python, c, compilation

I've been experimenting with C modules in python and I've had no problems with compilation. However, when it comes to importing the module I receive this error message:

```
>>> import _strrev
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /path/to/my/module.so: undefined symbol: strrev
```

The contents of the file are

*_strrev.c*

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <string.h>
static PyObject* _strrev(PyObject* self, PyObject *args) {
   PyObject* name;
   if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "U", &name)) {
       return NULL; 
   }
   PyObject *ret = strrev(*name); 

   return ret;
}

static struct PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"strrev", (PyCFunction)_strrev, METH_VARARGS},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, 
    "_strrev",
    NULL, 
    -1, 
    methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit__strrev(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&module);
}
```

*setup.py*

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(
        name='strrev_lib',
        version='1',
        ext_modules=[Extension('_strrev', ['_strrev.c'])],
        )
```

When running nm -D on this object file, I get this output

```
$ nm -D _strrev.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so 
                 w __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U PyArg_ParseTuple
00000000000011a0 T PyInit__strrev
                 U PyModule_Create2
                 U __stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4
                 U strrev
```

I can see that strrev is here, so I don't understand why it says that the symbol in undefined.

I've also tried using a different module and that works perfectly fine when attempting to import it.

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _hello
>>> _hello.hello("Jared")
'hello Jared'
```

The contents of the files are:
*_hello.c*

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* _hello(PyObject* self, PyObject *args) {
   PyObject* name;
   if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "U", &name)) {
       return NULL; 
   }
   PyObject *ret = PyUnicode_FromFormat("hello %U", name);

   return ret;
}

static struct PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"hello", (PyCFunction)_hello, METH_VARARGS},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, 
    "_hello",
    NULL, 
    -1, 
    methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit__hello(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&module);
}
```

*setup.py*

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import Extension

setup(
        name='hello-lib',
        version='1',
        ext_modules=[Extension('_hello', ['_hello.c'])],
        )
```

Can anyone give me pointers as to what I'm doing wrong? Is it something with the compilation or with the code that I've written? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see that strrev is here, so I don't understand why it says that the symbol in undefined.

Au contraire: you can see that `strrev` is *not* there -- `U` in `nm` output means *undefined*.

The `strrev` appears to be a [Windows thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strrev-wcsrev?view=msvc-170), and you are not on Windows. There is no such symbol in GLIBC:

```
$ nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep strrev
$
```

To fix this, you would need to implement `strrev()` yourself.